# How to set ManToManyField to None?

Tags: django, django-models, model, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I have a Section model for storing different sections of laws.
A law has `Part`, `Book`, `Chapter`, `Title`, `Section`, `SubSection`, ... and `Article`

[image]

Instead of making models for each of the above parts, I created a section model to store the sections in the database.

The level field in the section model specifies the depth of levels. as you can see in the picture.

```
class Section(Timestamped):
    parent = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='self',
        verbose_name=_("Parent Section"),
        help_text=_("Specifies the links to another section."),
        blank=True,
        symmetrical=False
    )
    level = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_("Level of the section"),
    )
    ...
```

**My problem** is that when I store the first section or level, the parent should be set to null(which means that the first section has no parent). But I get an error when I set the parent to None.

I have all the sections in a JSON file:

**The script**
for section in sections:
section_data = {
"text_id": section.get("id"),
"level": 1,
}
section_db, created = Section.objects.get_or_create(**section_data)
section_db.parent.add(None)

**The error**

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "to_section_id" of relation "laws_section_parent" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (3, 22, null).
```

Is there any solution?
Are the models correctly designed?

Comment: I think parent should be a `ForeignKey` field holding its direct parent. That way, you can store top level sections with `parent=None`.

Comment: Thanks, @Marco, Your comment makes sense. Let me try it.